# Error: googleapi: Error 400: Composer API Service Agent service account error

Tags: cloud, google-cloud-composer

Error: googleapi: Error 400: Composer API Service Agent service account (service-project#@cloudcomposer-accounts.iam.gserviceaccount.com) does not have required permissions set. Cloud Composer API Service Agent role is missing. Please bind roles/composer.serviceAgent back on service-project#

I am deploying composer cluster. Both roles "roles/composer.serviceAgent" and "roles/composer.ServiceAgentV2Ext" were given. Maybe you guys had better luck with this error ?

not able to resolve.

Comment: Did you try to create a cloud composer through the console ? or via terraform for example ?

Comment: I tried to create via terraform.

Comment: The first time you create a Cloud Composer on a project, you need to give the 2 roles you mentionned manually to the service account `service-project#@cloudcomposer-accounts.iam.gserviceaccount.com`.
Try to do it via the console. You should see a "Grant required permissions to Cloud Composer service account" section appears. You can check the documentation here : https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/create-environments